# LibreOffice: How to add a new button to toolbar?

Tags: libreoffice

I want to add a button of "left-to-right". I opened Tools -> Customize -> Toolbar, and I saw that this button is marked. Still, I don't see it in my toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Buttons `Left-To-Right` and `Right-To-Left` are enabled by default in the `Formatting`-toolbar. So you wouldn't need to add them to the `Standard`-toolbar. But these buttons are only visible if you have `Complex text layout (CTL)` enabled in `Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages`. After enabling this setting you will have to restart LibreOffice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to add a button...

make sure your toolbar is not too long so it is hiding some buttons on the right with >>

And maybe the button your looking for is not looking exactly the same as in the customize menu...

hope this help

Comment: If you take a deeper look into the provided screenshot you will see that there are no hidden buttons in the toolbar.