# Is there a way to make Libre Office more responsive in order to be able to center text while the window is in half-screen display

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, customization, debugging

So first of all I am using Libre Office with the following settings:

```
Version: 6.0.7.3   
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2   
CPU threads:8; OS: Linux 4.18; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3;    
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group
```

And so whan I am using it in half-screen mode (so using 2 applications side-by-side) I would like to **center some text** BUT I can't because the centering button is not available!

My current screen: as you can see the "center text" button is hidden and not available

[image: half-screen mode]

but in "full screen" mode I can see it on the right:

[image: fullscreen]

Do you please know any ways to fix it ? It seems libre office is kind of non-responsive so that's kinda annoying to use.

edit: screenshot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+E ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The toolbar requires a minimum screen width. If you want all buttons to remain in view, make sure you make your windows wide enough, or work with a maximized window.

Alternatively, you can customize the toolbars or change their location. You can edit toolbars and remove items, or move them to new toolbars. You can customize toolbars and other interface elements under `Tools` - `Customize`. You can also right-click the toolbar handle to access settings for changing it.

[The answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910391/libreoffice-how-to-add-a-new-button-to-toolbar) indicates how it can be done for prior versions of Libreoffice. For recent versions, that dialog has changed. Select the toolbar you want to customize from the dropdown menu under `Target`. Click the cog symbol under `Target` to add new toolbars.

Alternatively, grab the handle of the toolbar and drag it. You can place a toolbar vertically along the left or right side of the window by dragging it.

Thus, Libreoffice allows the flexibility to rearrange the interface in a way that works best for you.

Comment: I am surprised by your comment. In your question, you are posting a graphic and clearly referring to the icons to the right on the standard toolbar.

Comment: Well I'm not an english native speaker I guess we're talking about the same thing but I just used the wrong words to describe it, sorry for that. I am still  referring to the icons to the right on the standard toolbar.

Comment: That is what my answer is referring to.

Comment: I know that's why I upvoted your answer, however I cannot find the dropdown menu under `Target`. I did `Tools` > `Customize` > `Toolbars`

Comment: I have 6.1.5.2 that comes with Ubuntu 18.10. "Target" is the second item in the right half, under "Scope", and just above "Function". It might be that that dialog has changed. I may update my answer.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I updated my question by adding a screenshot.

Comment: Now you have been pointed to the possibility to edit toolbars, what are you still looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to edit the bottom toolbar (the one containing the text size, font, centering etc..) I only found how to edit the top toolbar so far

Comment: Where it says "Standard", click and a drop down will appear, allowing you to select another toolbar.

Comment: I know but precisely I cannot find how to update the toolbar I want to, the `Standard`is the one at the top, and I cannot find anyone called `Target`

Comment: The dialog has changed in the latest version. You do not have a "Target" section in the dialog.

Comment: Ok I have no ideas how to find it so, it's so bad, we're so close.

Comment: It is the button labeled "Standard"

Comment: it is not the standard I already tried, I am using the`Version: 6.0.7.3` of Libre office which looks different from yours, I just found it ! it is called `Formatting` in my version.